# Using LINQ for List of type object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type object as such

```
List<object> _list;
```

I initialize this list in a method and add a few items with properties

```
void CreateList()
{
_list= new List<object>();
_list.Add(new {Prop1 = 45, Prop2 = "foo", Prop3 = 4.5});
_list.Add(new {Prop1 = 14, Prop2 = "bar", Prop3 = 3.1});
}
```

However i now have a list of type object and i don't know it's type or the type of the elements.

I want to select a few elements based on their properties from the list using LINQ e.g. FindAll().
How do i go about this? Would it be better to create a POCO class?

Comment: Create strongly typed poco would work. Alternatives could be to use `dynamic` but strongly typed tends to be better than duck typing

Comment: Why it's of type `object`? You could've used `ArrayList`. The whole point of `Generics` it to use strongly typed object.

Comment: You should use strongly defined class, instead of anonymous, and strongly typed `List`, instead of the most general `List<object>`.

Comment: @Mahmoud i figured that using type object, if someone were to add things, it would be easier for them and not affect other code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I now have a list of type object and I don't know it's type or the type of the elements.

That's what you get for using `object` as element type. You still have multiple options available to you:

- If you can create a class to represent list items, the problem is solved
- If you can create your List in the same context where you use it, you could use `var` to capture the anonymous type
- If you don't have either of these options, cast to `dynamic` and forego static type checking

The second option would look like this:

```
var list = (new[] {
    new {Prop1 = 45, Prop2 = "foo", Prop3 = 4.5}
,   new {Prop1 = 14, Prop2 = "bar", Prop3 = 3.1}
}).ToList();
...
var filtered = list.Where(x => x.Prop1==45).ToList();
```

The third option would look like this:

```
var filtered = _list
    .Cast<dynamic>()
    .Where(x => x.Prop1==45) // <<== No static type checking here
    .Cast<object>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The second way is genius indeed! I didn't think about it. Thank you!

Comment: I can go with either the first or third option since i'm using the list elsewhere. A strongly typed class does seem like the better idea as suggested by many.

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 7.0 you can also use the new `ValueTuple`s.

```
List<(int Prop1, string Prop2, double Prop3)> _list;

void CreateList()
{
    _list = new List<(int Prop1, string Prop2, double Prop3)>();
    _list.Add((45, "foo", 4.5));  // Positional
    _list.Add((Prop1: 14, Prop2: "bar", Prop3: 3.1)); // Named
}
```

---

If the default names given by C# are sufficient you can omit the names when declaring the tuple. They will be given the names `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3`.

```
List<(int, string, double)> _list;

void CreateList()
{
    _list = new List<(int, string, double)>();
    _list.Add((45, "foo", 4.5));
    _list.Add((14, "bar", 3.1));
}
```

or

```
void CreateList()
{
    _list = new List<(int, string, double)> {
        (45, "foo", 4.5),
        (14, "bar", 3.1)
    };
}
```

Select an item by its default name:

```
int i = _list[0].Item1;
```

Decompose the tuple into local the variables `int a; string b; double c;`

```
var (a, b, c) = _list[0];
```

---

Tuples and anonymous types are great for intermediate results and for a local usage. For public APIs, prefer POCO classes, interfaces and structs.